# Unable to install ADT 17.0.0 on genuitec MyEclipse 8.6 IDE

Tags: android, adt, myeclipse

I am trying to install Android ADT 17.0.0 on genuitec MyEclipse 8.6 IDE but it gives me error saying

> Software being installed: MyEclipse 8.6 (Profile)
>   2.0.0.0000000004com.poweredbypulse.profile-2671763-rmb-3375160 2.0.0.0000000004)
>   Missing requirement:
>   Android DDMS 17.0.0.v201203161636-291853 (com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms.feature.group 
>   17.0.0.v20120316163

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both eclipse and MyEclipse have a "dropins" folder, which can be used to install plug-ins. The dropins folder will ensure a proper install is done. The jar files can be put directly in the dropins folder or in a "plugins" subfolder of the dropins folder.

Not sure if that was the full message you saw on the install. These messages, in both eclipse and myeclipse are a bit confusing.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

Unzip ADT 17.0.0

Open folder **ADT 17.0.0 > plugins**

copy all JAR files from plugins folder

then paste it to

**eclipse > plugins**

then restart your eclipse

Comment: I am using MyEclipse not eclipse

Comment: i am able to install ADT 14 but when I try to install ADT 17 it gives me the above error